# Unable To Print Multipage Print Preview With NStableView Data Cocoa App

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsprintoperation

I want to Print NSTableVIew data as multi page print preview but print preview shows only first few records rest pages are empty.I am using below code to print NStableView data.

```
let printInfo = NSPrintInfo.shared
printInfo.paperSize = NSSize(width: self.reporttableview.frame.width , height: 800.00)
printInfo.verticalPagination = .automatic
let operation: NSPrintOperation = NSPrintOperation(view: self.reporttableview, printInfo: printInfo)
operation.printPanel.options.insert([.showsPaperSize, .showsOrientation])
operation.run()
```

Above code working fine with minimum records like 30 -40 rows but when record is around 100 or more than 100 its only print first few records and rest pages are empty.Any help will be really appreciated.I have attached tableview and Print preview screen shots for better understanding.

1. TableView Records:
   [Table view screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQKrw.png)
2. Print Preview:
   [Print preview screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60OBT.jpg)
   You can see in above screen shot only first few pages having records rest are empty.And if I scroll table view in that case whole print Preview is empty.
   [Empty print preview screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elF8B.png)

I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What you are trying to do sounds like the same as trying to print out the entire content inside a scroll view.

Comment: Yes @ElTomato you are right but when I am trying to print whole ScrollView its only print scroll view existing frame area. I have also tried to assigned Tableview frames to scroll view content offset but nothing works.

Comment: I tried your code and all rows are printed. Post a [mre] please.

Comment: @Willeke please try with at least 100 records in table view.with limited data like 30 - 40 records its working fine.

Comment: I tried 100 and 10000 rows. Is it possible to reproduce the issue in a small test project?

Comment: Are all your questions about the same PDF export? Do you want to export the table view or a report?

Comment: I don't know whether it is possible or not in small project but I am simply using NStableView. Yes my all questions are Around PDF and PDF print view rest all has been already done in project. I have edit my question and attached few screen shots of TableView data and PDF for better understanding.

Comment: @Willeke I want to export table view data as report in same format as showing in TableView screen shot.

Comment: Is the datasource/delegate object deallocated?

Comment: I have doubled checked everything is fine table view showing all the data and while print datasources as also connected. As I told earlier upto 100 records there is no issue but when records are more than 100 than its start creating problem in Multipage print preview. If I am scrolling table view from top to bottom in that case print preview only creating empty pages without any data.

Comment: The cause of the issue is not in the code you posted.

Comment: Do you have any idea what can be the cause of issue?

Comment: I think Viewcontroller reallocated when print preview present?

Comment: Create a [mre] and you'll find what's causing the crash.

Comment: Yes I have created New POC to check above issue but could not find any error or issue in code. I am using  View Based TableView and this time I have created singleton instance of ViewController. I have observed Print Preview only print visible cell data in print preview. This is only happening for multipage Print preview single page preview is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I believe it is caused by the method AppKit uses to display NSTableViews efficiently. This seems to optimise, i.e. reduce, the memory load of large NSTableViews by only generating display data for about 3 "pages" of the view. To get the entire NSTableView to print, set the NSTableView instance property `var usesStaticContents: Bool { get set }` to true before printing (and return its value to false once printing is completed). I have tested this successfully on a table of 33 x A4 landscape pages and it works fine (although it takes ~5 seconds before the print panel is displayed).

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
struct ReportsDetailView: View {
        
    @Binding var reportNodes: [ReportNode]
    @State private var viewToPrint = NSView()
    @State private var printing = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ReportsDetailTableVC(reportNodes: $reportNodes, viewToPrint: $viewToPrint, printing: $printing)
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button("Print Report") {
                    printing = true
                    let scale: CGFloat = 800/viewToPrint.frame.width
                    let printInfo = NSPrintInfo()
                    printInfo.horizontalPagination = .automatic
                    printInfo.verticalPagination = .automatic
                    printInfo.isVerticallyCentered = true
                    printInfo.isHorizontallyCentered = true
                    printInfo.printer = NSPrinter(name: NSPrinter.printerNames[0])!
                    printInfo.paperSize = NSSize(width: 595.28, height: 841.89)
                    printInfo.topMargin = 10
                    printInfo.bottomMargin = 10
                    printInfo.leftMargin = 10
                    printInfo.rightMargin = 10
                    printInfo.orientation = .landscape
                    printInfo.scalingFactor = scale
                    let printOperation = NSPrintOperation(view: viewToPrint, printInfo: printInfo)
                    printOperation.run()
                    printing = false
                }
                .disabled(printing)
            }
            .padding(10)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

struct ReportsDetailTableVC: NSViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    @Binding var reportNodes: [ReportNode]
    @Binding var viewToPrint: NSView
    @Binding var printing: Bool
    
    func makeNSViewController(context: Context) -> some NSViewController {
        let reportsDetailVC = ReportsDetailTableViewController()
        return reportsDetailVC
    }
    
    func updateNSViewController(_ nsViewController: NSViewControllerType, context: Context) {
        guard let reportsDetailVC = nsViewController as? ReportsDetailTableViewController else {return}
        reportsDetailVC.setContents(reportNodes: reportNodes)
        if printing {
            reportsDetailVC.tableView.scrollRowToVisible(0)
            reportsDetailVC.tableView.usesStaticContents = true
            reportsDetailVC.tableView.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .aqua)
            reportsDetailVC.tableView.usesAlternatingRowBackgroundColors = false
        }
        else {
            reportsDetailVC.tableView.usesStaticContents = false
            reportsDetailVC.tableView.appearance = colorScheme == .light ? NSAppearance(named: .aqua) : NSAppearance(named: .darkAqua)
            reportsDetailVC.tableView.usesAlternatingRowBackgroundColors = true
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {viewToPrint = reportsDetailVC.tableView}
    }
}
```